# Does editing a text file replace/wipe the bytes written on the hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

So when you delete a file on a PC it removes the pointer of that file rather than the actual bytes, that remains until it is written over.

If you have a txt that simply has the word "Hello" and I charge the contents to "Aljoe" does this change write over the original bytes of the file or does it just remove the pointer of that and create another file of same attributes but different contents.

Does this mean that "Hello" txt file is recoverable or has the "Aljoe" text replaced that file.

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I guess you have clicked Save?  I ask since the person that recently posted an answer, attie,  doesn't seem to make that assumption, in fact he may even assume that you didn't click save.

Comment: If you mean you didn't click save, then your question would be a bit absurd, since you can easily open the file and see it didn't change it.  But the person that posted an answer , attie, has presumed you mean you didn't click save, since he talks about a temporary file that some editors use, which is irrelevant if you did click save. And anyhow, if changes were saved to a temporary file and not to the original, you'd know and wouldn't have to ask. So if you think Attie's answer is wrong and makes wrong assumptions then please comment and say so..

Comment: 'cos either Attie is making bad assumptions that make your question absurd,  or your question is absurd. One or the other.

Comment: @barlop it is assuming that i have pressed save to "Hello" file closed the text editor, opened that file again removed "Hello" from it and wrote "Aljoe" then clicked save again or ctrl + s

Comment: I can't be absolutely certain but i'm pretty sure the original text is overwritten and gone.   If you tried an undelete program I think it won't get it because the bytes are overwritten.   Undelete programs aren't known for getting previous revisions of a file!   If it did delete a pointer to old data and store new data elsewhere then they'd be known for getting previous revisions of a file!  Or people would undelete a file and have to choose what version, or would get a vresion of a file from an earlier save, which one never hears of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on many factors - including your chosen editor, the filesystem and storage technology...

#### Editor

Some editors will simply re-write the file.

However many editors will create a temporary file, which is written to completion and then renamed to replace the old file. This makes the "save" operation atomic - that is, the file will definitely contain either A) the old content, or B) the new content. Writing the file 'in-place' opens up potential for partially written files or corruption if part of the system fails (e.g: power loss, or the application crashes).

Consider the following pseudo code / steps:

```
# user opens file "myfile.txt"
f = open("myfile.txt", "r")
buffer = f.read()

# user edits file in-memory

# saves file as "myfile.txt"
f = open("_myfile.txt", "w")
f.write(buffer)
f.close()
rename("_myfile.txt", "myfile.txt")
```

If you're interested in technical details here, then you may be interested to know that when using such an editor, the file's inode / file ID may change on each save... We start to get into a philosophical discussion about what "*the file*" actually is... For now, let's consider "*the file*" to be the data accessible at a named location in the filesystem (the filename).

#### Filesystem

Even if your editor was "dumb", and just re-wrote the contents of the file, the filesystem in use is potentially able to record the "new" data anywhere that it deems suitable, and in some cases they will do a similar technique to above - write a new block to completion, and then re-link the file table.

This may be necessary for a number of reasons, including the possibility that there isn't enough free space in that location for the new data.

#### Storage Technology (Disk)

When you consider SSDs, things go even further. When you "write to a physical location" on an SSD, you are actually writing to a completely unrelated **truly** physical area in flash, that is completely unknown to you - the SSD keeps a map of the "physical" to "true physical" blocks.

SSDs and other flash storage will also typically write data to pre-erased pages (as this is faster and more convenient) rather than erasing a given page to re-write there. This helps with wear levelling as well, otherwise working on a text file for a day could see the cells wear out if it's content resided in the same physical flash cells throughout.

#### Conclusion

So... with the information you've given, I'd suspect that it's highly unlikely that simply "*modifying the text in a file*" will actually remove the old text from persistent storage.

---

#### Proof

Want to try it for yourself? Run this on Linux:

Make a filesystem and mount it:

```
$ truncate -s $(( 10 * 1024 * 1024 )) myfs.ext2
$ mkfs.ext2 ./myfs.ext2
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 10240 1k blocks and 2560 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 42d13441-a9c1-44e1-9310-275c92c60f15
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        8193

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ mkdir mnt
$ sudo mount -o loop ./myfs.ext2  ./mnt
$ sudo chown attie: ./mnt
```

Check upfront to see if "*Hello*" is in what is effectively the disk's data (it's not):

```
$ grep "Hello" myfs.ext2
```

Write a "*Hello*" to `myfile.txt` in the filesystem:

```
$ echo "Hello" > ./mnt/myfile.txt
$ sync
```

Check to see if "*Hello*" is there now (it is):

```
$ grep "Hello" myfs.ext2
Binary file myfs.ext2 matches
$ cat ./mnt/myfile.txt
Hello
```

Write "*Aljoe*" to `myfile.txt`:

```
$ echo "Aljoe" > ./mnt/myfile.txt
$ sync
```

Check to see if "*Hello*" is there now (it's still "on disk", but not in the file):

```
$ grep "Hello" myfs.ext2
Binary file myfs.ext2 matches
$ cat ./mnt/myfile.txt
Aljoe
```

This will work for simple `echo`, but also for `vim`.

---

#### Update

I have just tried this on Windows (which is less available for me), and it looks like both FAT and NFTS will re-use storage that has been allocated, while ext2/3/4 will allocate new storage.

Additionally, a quick review of Notepad++ and Atom show that the "write and rename" approach isn't used as I had expected - while it *is* used by applications such as `vim`.

I think that a more correct answer might be:

- If you're running Windows, then the data is probably overwritten immediately.
- If you're running Linux, then the data probably remains in persistent storage.

"*Probably*", because there are of course exceptions to these statements.

Comment: Worth checking if the person asking the question is saying he clicked Save. I think it's most likely that he is, (otherwise his question is a bit daft), and if he did click safe, then much of what you wrote about a temporary file is completely irrelevant, and things about it depending on the editor are then irrelevant.

Comment: -1 As I expected, he had clicked save. This has nothing to do with temporary files, and it is not editor dependent. You can assume notepad.

Comment: @barlop if they didn't click "save", then his question about the data on the hard disk would be irrelevant. What I wrote about a "temporary" file is actually very relevant, as (if you read the text), using a temporary file allows "atomic" saves, where the the file definitely contains either new content or old, and never partial data.

Comment: He did click save, as I expected, and his question about the data on his hard drive is not irrelevant at all.  Maybe you don't understand his question if you think it's irrelevant. Why do you think he even asked his question?

Comment: @barlop review my clarifications, and be sure to read carefully...

Comment: Much of what you have written is still completely irrelevant because he is not talking about an editor that uses temporary files. And besides, many of your statements are ambiguous.. including most significantly your conclusion, making it useless.

Comment: Anyhow, while I have pointed out issues with your answer you only act maliciously against my answer by deliberately not stating any factual error in it, or any way in which my answer is not relevant.

Comment: "_he is not talking about an editor that uses temporary files_" - how on earth can you claim that??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69926/discussion-between-barlop-and-attie).

Answer (score -1):

I can't be absolutely certain but i'm pretty sure , like 99% sure, the original text is overwritten and gone. If you tried an undelete program I think it won't get it because the bytes are overwritten. Undelete programs aren't known for getting previous revisions of a file! If it did delete a pointer to old data and store new data elsewhere then they'd be known for getting previous revisions of a file! Or people would undelete a file and have to choose what version, or would get a version of a file from an earlier save, which one never hears of.

Comment: This answer is far from factual, and misses many of the technical details included in my answer.

Comment: The ramblings about "undelete programs" are either poorly considered, or come from a technically ignorant source.

Comment: @Attie What are you talking about. You haven't stated any error in what I have written.

Comment: "_I can't be absolutely certain but i'm pretty sure , like 99% sure_"... please explain how you are so sure.

Comment: @Attie My third sentence onwards addresses that.

Comment: "_Undelete programs aren't known for getting previous revisions of a file!_"... such utilities, and concepts as "_files_" are much more complex than simply "_looking in the right place_". If you were to run through the raw storage, looking for the "Hello", then I suspect you'd find it.

Comment: @Attie   I am not ruling it out 100%, but have you ever heard of an undeletion program (And undelete programs DO go through raw storage), finding a previous version of a file?

Comment: A file is a collection of blocks that are gathered, ordered and presented to the user as a "thing"... the fact that reassembling it can be tricky doesn't make it impossible... yes I have reassembled fragments of files from disk.